# How to calculate field in Model based on other table?

Tags: sql, model, atk4

I have one model:

```
class Model_Alumno extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='alumno';
function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->defineAuditFields();

    $this->addField('name')->caption('Nombre del Alumno')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('is_inscrito')->type('boolean')->calculated(true);
}
function calculate_is_inscrito(){
    what goes here????
}

}
```

I wanto to calculate is_inscrito as Y or N, if a record with it's id exists in some other table, so I can use an SQL like this:

> SELECT IF( (SELECT count(*) FROM programaPago, alumno WHERE
>   alumno_id=**CORRESPONDING ID**)>0, 'Y', 'N')

How can I write the calculate_is_inscrito function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculate_is_inscrito(){
    return "IF( (SELECT count(*) FROM programaPago, alumno WHERE alumno_id=".
        ($this->table_alias?:$this->entity_code).".id)>0, 'Y', 'N')";
}
```